# Use one of the two incoming observable stream to filter data in angular

Tags: rxjs, angular8

> I have the below code I have the formcontrol value (its a multicheckbox list), the values is an array of true/false, [true, false, true, true, ...]. This is one of the many lists
>   I also have the data list - collection of objects of structure {id: number, desc: string, disabled:  boolean, selected: boolean} 
>   I need to retrieve the id matching the true by matching index, and set an observable 
>   I have the below code

```
 valueChanged(e: any, name: string, key: string, valuesArray: string) {
        this.hasChanged = true;
        from(name).pipe(
            debounceTime(200),
            withLatestFrom(this[name].value), // this[name] is form array, gives [true, false, false,..]
            mergeMap(values => forkJoin(
                of(values),
                this[valuesArray].find(val => val.name === name).data
                )),
            mergeMap(([values, data]) => {
            flatMap((val, i) => val ? data[i].id : null),
            filter(id => id !== null),
            map(ids => {
                this.selectedFilters[key] = ids;
                switch (key) {
                    case 'groupId':
                        this.curGroup.next(ids);
                        break;
                }
            });
        })
        );
    }
```

> I need help on the line flatmap where I want to use values, for each of the value (true/false), if val[i] is true, include data[i].id in the output i want he id array of true values [1,2,4,5,..]. I get the error 
>   Argument of type '([values, data]: [[string, unknown], unknown]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [[string, unknown], unknown], index: number) => ObservableInput'.
>     Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.ts(2345)
>
> Need help on how to use solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: pretty much none of this code is valid. you're accessing synchronous variable as though they're observables all over the place. Break your code into smaller pieces and try to make them work one by one instead of trying to write the whole thing at once.

Comment: This is my first attempt at higher order observables. Can you please post a sample? that would be helpful

Comment: you don't need to use ANY observables in this function from what I can tell.